# Does long query better than some short queries?

Tags: sql, performance

I have server written in NodeJs and it has db from Sql Server.

I need to write some update queries. So is there any different between one query:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Groups]
SET [GroupName] = 'bb'
WHERE GroupId='2058'
GO

UPDATE [dbo].[Groups]
SET [GroupName] = 'bb2'
  ,[Image] = NULL
  ,[img] = NULL
WHERE GroupId='2059'
GO
```

Or writing 2 queries and run each one separately:

1.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Groups]
   SET [GroupName] = 'bb'
 WHERE GroupId='2058'
```

2.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Groups]
   SET [GroupName] = 'bb2'
      ,[Image] = NULL
      ,[img] = NULL
 WHERE GroupId='2059'
```

Is there any difference between the performances?

Comment: Yes, there is a difference.  How minuscule that difference, and which way is better is impossible to determine with the information given.  Try asking something more specific or perhaps more general... I'm not really sure, because it's hard to tell what you're getting at.

Comment: To my knowledge; no there is no difference in performance scale.

Comment: @Rahul: Not true.  If you could run these in parallel, and one returned a bunch of data, it is quite possible that the other one could finish, do calculations on data, and continue along.  While the query time might be the same (I'm not convinced it is, it is at the very least system dependent), the performance implications are significant.  So to suggest to the OP that the methods are not different is incorrect.  Hence, we don't have enough information.

Comment: @ChrisCM, Run them in parallel? That's never going to happen cause the UPDATE is happening on same table and it will acquire a exclusive lock on the table.

Comment: @ChrisCM, I have no idea about Node app but running an parallel UPDATE on same table .. it's just against DBMS transaction concept. Not sure what you are referring to?

Comment: @Rahul: Let's say you have two updates.  One that registers a new theme park, and one that registers a guest at a different theme park.  If you were to post the new guest first, you could start a new paraellel line of work with that guest, then post the new theme park, and wait for the callback to be called.  However, if you were to post the new guest and in the same xact post the new theme park, the work you were doing on the new guest has to wait for the entire new theme park to be added.  The amount of work your SQL server is doing is equivalent, but the downtime on your event loop is not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a difference between the 2 queries. The first one runs your 2 queries in batch, the second one not. When running multiple queries in batch, the performance is usually better then running them separately because of network overhead and latency.